# How does Redshift treat guillemets?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to run a CSV import using the `COPY` command for some data that includes a guillemet (`»`). Redshift complains that the column value is too long for the `varchar` column I have defined. The error in the "Loads" tab in the Redshift GUI displays this character as two dots: `..` - had it been treated as one, it would have fit in the `varchar` column. It's not clear whether there is some sort of conversion error occurring or if there is a display issue.

When trying to do plain `INSERT`s I run into strange behavior as well:

```
dev=# create table test (name varchar(3));
CREATE TABLE
dev=# insert into test values ('bla');
INSERT 0 1
```

3 characters treated as 4?

```
dev=# insert into test values ('bl»');

ERROR:  value too long for type character varying(3)

dev=# insert into test values ('b»');

INSERT 0 1
```

Why does `char_length` return 2?

```
dev=# select char_length(name), name from test;

char_length | name
-------------+------
           2 | b»
```

I've checked the client encoding and database encodings and those all seem to be UTF8/UNICODE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the length of your varchar field. Multibyte characters use more than one character and length in the definition of varchar field are byte based. So, your special char might be taking more than a byte. If it still doesn't work refer to the doc page for Redshift below,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/multi-byte-character-load-errors.html

Comment: I thought that at first too, but I would expect to see a UTF-8 related error like those listed on that page as opposed to the "too long" error message I saw.

Comment: It might actually be taking more than one char for each multibyte character and your column size is not enough for that. Did you try increasing the size of your column, are you still getting the same issue?

Comment: In my example above, notice the third INSERT succeeded when I tried just the 2 characters `b»` so increasing the column size would work. This behavior just seems to be different than what's described in the documentation and I'm trying to understand why that is.